# Getting same jobs done by automatic

Tags: automation

For a loooong time, I have been wondering, how I can get some very basic jobs done on my Windows compputers.
The case is this, that I have 3 machines. Once a month, I do some of the same jobs over and over again like update Windows, running Diskcleaner, running a deep Diskcleaner, running a deep antivirus scan, doing Diskfragtment, checking for updates on a various amouth of programs and 3rd party programs, running Ccleaner and so on.

These tasks take time, and I was wondering how I can get this done automatically. It is the same things I do every months, and I was thinking that an IT administrator in a big company with like 400 machines or more, MUST have an automatic solution for this. I really dont believe that this guy has to sign into all those 400 machines manually one by one to do like updating windows or so.

So what can I use for solving this? I have been trying few kinds of Macro software with no luck, I am not a coding guy so I cant use Windows Task Manager.

Can someone build a program for me, that can do this?

Thanks!